# No syntax highlight for *.qss file in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt4, syntax-highlighting, qt-creator

It's wired that Qt Creator didn't have a syntax highlight for its own style file format , or did i missed some packages ?
[image]

VER: Qt Creator 2.1.0

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I could not find any evidence in Qt's documentation that `.qss` is an officially designated file extension. I'd say just change it to `.css`.

Comment: **QSS ≠ CSS.** The two only superficially resemble one another; they're distinct languages and should be distinguished as such. See [Gerstmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403018/gerstmann)'s [sensible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7625107/2809027), which preserves this critical distinction.

Answer (score 36):

Go to

> Tools > Options > Environment > Mime types

Find `text/css` and add `*.qss` to patterns.

Comment: This is the most correct answer imo because QSS != CSS, so it makes sense to keep them in files with a different ending.

Comment: Basically set it to `*.css;*.qss`