# Qt4 css - How to create file .QSS?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a question.

How do I create in my project folder with a file. `.QSS` ?

At the option of creating new files do not have this extension!

I would be very grateful for the help.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624656/no-syntax-highlight-for-qss-file-in-qt-creator Have you tried just using the file as a .css?

Comment: Not yet. You know how I create a folder in the project? to just put my css style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Control+N
2. -> General
3. -> Chooose
4. In name write style.qss (you may also choose the directory)
5. Add to project, or SVN
6. Drink a coffie or beer

Comment: In which program would one type Ctrl+N in your example above?

Comment: QtCreator. Choose general as the type (Qt Creator 4.0/4.1)

Answer (score 5):

Just create it with a text editor like a notepad and save it with the `.qss` extension. I suggest to add it in your resource file.

You can load it using the following sample code

```
QFile file(":/qss/style.qss");
if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
   QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(file.readAll());
   qApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Qt Creator (I'm assuming that is what you are using) is a little lacking in this area. Just create the folder and file on your file system. Then, in Qt Creator, right click on the project and select `Add Existing Files...`